export 'ɵsetClassDebugInfo' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
I try to use package https://github.com/nativescript-community/ui-drawer and faced with this error
 ERROR in ./node_modules/@nativescript-community/ui-drawer/angular/fesm2022/nativescript-community-ui-drawer-angular.mjs 58:60-81
 export 'ɵsetClassDebugInfo' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core' (possible exports: ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE,

my environment
 #ng version
 Angular CLI: 15.1.4
 Node: 18.17.0
 Package Manager: npm 10.0.0
 OS: win32 x64
 Angular: 16.2.12
 ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
 ... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
 Package                         Version
 ---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1602.14
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.2.14
@angular-devkit/core            16.2.14
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.1.4 (cli-only)
@ngtools/webpack                16.2.14
@schematics/angular             15.1.4 (cli-only)
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.1.6

Error faced in line
(() => { (typeof ngDevMode === "undefined" || ngDevMode) && i0.ɵsetClassDebugInfo(DrawerComponent, { className: "DrawerComponent", filePath: "module.ts", lineNumber: 26 }); })();


Maybe this package is expired, how is possible to replace this line to modern Angular version?
In Angular framework this class mentions in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/core/src/render3/index.ts

The version of @nativescript-community/ui-drawer isn't compatible with your v16 app.
It looks like to only support v17.

Thank you, maybe you are right, but I updated all Angular in my computer to version 18. But NG VERSION show me strange result Angular CLI: 18.0.3, Node: 22.2.0, Package Manager: npm 10.8.1, OS: win32 x64, Angular: 16.2.12, ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, ... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router. So, all Angular in my computer is new V18, but next line after OS show Angular 16 and issue still present.

Please have a look on how to update projects : https://angular.dev/update-guide

Of course, this is absolutely not workable instruction. Response for "ng update @angular/core@18 @angular/cli@18" in any computers and environments I have seen always "Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace." I have access to 3-4 computers, on each of them I see the same result. And, of course, I type this command exactly in my workspace.

Are you running this at the same level as the package.json ?

Yes, I deleted any global angular version (accessible with PATH variables) and save local Angular 18 to project folder with force "npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest --force". After that project finally dead. And now I can restore it at all. This is nativescript project and after I force to change to Angular 18 (this is requirements of community-drawer) gradle script stop working at all "Error: spawn EINVAL". I try create NS project from scratch and move to it my source code, but failed, project not pass compiling. Currently, I have no workable projects at all as a result to update Ang

last error message of gradle script (after attempt to install Angular 18) is - Failed to read emitted package.json. Error is:  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:...\platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\app\package.json'

I have upload full log of this trouble to https://github.com/nativescript-community/ui-drawer/issues/34

Finally trouble fixed by updated nativescript
 npm i -g nativescript@latest

